# Unable to change border color of Edit Text on focus

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to color my EditText border as blue when it is having focus. I tried all possible ways as suggested in many answers in Stack Overflow but it doesn't work. It is only changing color of cursor and not of whole border when focused. Below is what I tried, let me know if I am doing incorrectly

[image]

That grey border to blue color

styles.xml

```
<!--Edit Text-->
    <style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF1792E5</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FF1792E5</item>
    </style>
```

edit_text_border.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FF1792E5"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

XML

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtName"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                android:inputType="text|textCapWords"
                android:maxLength="40"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:singleLine="true" />
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: Try to change your edittext's background in setOnFocusChangeListener() of edittext.

Answer (score 0):

try this create a **edittext_focused_blue** in **res/drawable** folder like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />    
   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff00" />
   <corners android:radius="5dp" />

 </shape>
```

this create a edittext_normal in res/drawable folder like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


 </shape>
```

try this create a **edittext_bg** in **res/drawable** folder like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focused_blue" 
        /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item  android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_normal" 
        /> <!-- default -->
      </selector>
```

than apply to your editext using **android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"** like this

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/edtName"
     android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
     android:inputType="text|textCapWords"
     android:maxLength="40"
     android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: can u explain more about it.

Comment: I implemented the same but it isn't reflecting the onfocus color. I suspect the style also playing role from Manifest. Hence i removed that too from Activity in Manifest, but still don't work. Any work around programatically? onFocus?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_pressed" 
        /> <!-- pressed -->    
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focused_blue" 
        /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_normal" 
        /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this create a folder in res/drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:color="@color/block" android:width="5dp"/>
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

</shape>
```

**XML:**

```
android:background="@drawable/yourborder"
```

**Here is output.**

[image]

**Another Way:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_focused" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_focused" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
</selector>
```

I hop this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code to achieve your design:

> Drawable Code:

`et_border1.xml` Drawable for unselected or unfocused edittext.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`et_border2.xml` Drawable for selected or  focused edittext.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FF1792E5" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`edit_text_border` drawable to show selected or unselected edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/et_border2" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/et_border2" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/et_border1" />
</selector>
```

> In 'layout file'

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtName"
        android:inputType="text|textCapWords"
        android:maxLength="40"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Add or remove color according to requirement

I hope it work for you.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested below code and it works very well.

```
<EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/ediittext_selector"
      android:hint="Demo"
      />
```

ediittext_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_border_selected" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_border_selected" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_border" />
</selector>
```

edit_text_border_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

  <solid android:color="#737373" />
  <stroke
      android:color="#FF4081"
      android:width="1dp" />

  <padding
      android:bottom="10dp"
      android:left="10dp"
      android:right="10dp"
      android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

edit_text_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

  <solid android:color="#737373" />
  <stroke
      android:color="#F78C1F"
      android:width="1dp" />

  <padding
      android:bottom="10dp"
      android:left="10dp"
      android:right="10dp"
      android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```